# Jquery contains method not work if the string has space

Tags: jquery, selenium-webdriver, automation, whitespace, contains

jQuery's `:contains` selector does not work if the string has space with it.
For example, I want to select a dropdown value (Ex: `1st Letter`) through jQuery.

If I give like below, it is working fine

```
$('.z-comboitem-text:contains(1st)')
```

If I give like below, it is not working

```
$('.z-comboitem-text:contains(1st letter)')
```

Please give your suggestions
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Well its working:

```js
$('.div:contains(1st letter)').css('color', 'red');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='div'>
  asdfasfafd asdfas
  dfa
   
   d asdf
  asdf
  asdf
  <strong>1st letter</strong>
  a
  sdf
  asdf
  as
  fas
  df
  a
  </div>
```

Now your question: *I want to select a dropdown value*

```js
$('select option:contains(1st letter)').css('color', 'red');

console.log($('select option:contains(1st letter)'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select>
  <option>select...</option>
  <option>1st letter</option>
  <option>2nd letter</option>
  <option>3rd letter</option>
</select>
```

Comment: When I tried with $('.z-comboitem-text:contains("1st")'). I got output as <span class="z-comboitem-text">1st&nbsp;Letter</span>. But not working for "1st Letter"

Comment: `console.log($('select option:contains(1st letter)'));` this gave me the option which contains the `1st letter`.